# ssh/scp works but rsync just constantly says "no"

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync, scp, cygwin

Hi I have a windows 2003 server that I need to back up onto a `linux` client so I install `cygwin` on the `Win2k3`. On the `Win2k3` I have enabled `ssh`, `scp` but (because the `Win2k3` server uses an customised windows SFTP server listening on port 22) I had to set `scp` / `ssh` to run on `port 222` on cygwin. It works fine. As long as I use ssh/scp and use the -p/-P switch at command line.

I established a `SSH Public/Private Key Pair` for my user over ssh/scp it works lovely from `linux client` to `Win2k3 server`.

I then I start the rsyncd on Win2k3 and add the user in the `/etc/rsyncd.conf`, created the `/etc/rsyncd.secrets` and assigned privilages and it seems fine.

Then when I try to rsync connect /not/ over ssh it works but I want to /only/ connect via ssh and when I do that it fails every time with 0 bytes. I have tried multiple users and rewritten the rsyncd.conf a million times but it constantly fails. I am beginning to think I need to tell rsync client that the ssh port is 222 from the clients perspective. If so how do I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, of course you have to:

```
rsync -e 'ssh -p 222' ...
```

or:

```
RSYNC_RSH='ssh -p 222' rsync ...
```

Alternatively, you can specify in `~/.ssh/config` that `ssh` connections to that host are to be on port 222 by default:

```
Host that-host
Port 222
```

Answer (score 1):

A very late answer, but one that may help others...

`rsync` runs in one of two modes.

1. You can run it across `ssh`, and the local `rsync` process will start an `rsync` process on the remote system to act as its server, with `ssh` providing the encrypted transport between the two systems. This mode is indicated by a single colon between the remote host and the remote path:

   ```
   rsync /path/to/local/ remote:/path/to/remote
   ```
2. You can run it as a daemon, and the local `rsync` process will connect directly to an already-running server `rsync` process. There is no encryption (or `ssh`) offered with this scenario. This mode is indicated by a double colon between the remote host and the remote path:

   ```
   rsync /path/to/local remote::/path/to/remote
   ```

You do not need to install an `ssh` server *and* an `rsync` daemon. Either one or the other is quite sufficient.

For a secure LAN, or where the file contents are public, the `rsync` daemon may be more suitable as it does not require users to be able to log on to the remote system. The `ssh` approach is better for insecure or untrusted networks (i.e. the Internet) but it does require either very careful set up or the ability for users to be able to log on to the remote system.

In your situation, where you want to be able to connect only over `ssh`, there is no point configuring or running an `rsync` daemon.